# Invalid receiver type 'NSInteger' when setting NSInteger property

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I get an error "Invalid receiver type 'NSInteger'" on this line in my implementation of a simple class:

```
        self.price = p; // this line throws error
```

Should I be specifying price as `copy`?  More details:

header file:

```
@interface SafeItem : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
    NSInteger price;
    NSString *category;
    NSInteger itemid;
    BOOL hasImage;
}

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger price;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *category;
@property NSInteger itemid;
@property BOOL hasImage;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString*) n price:(NSInteger) p category:(NSString*) c; 

@end
```

implementation:

```
@implementation SafeItem

@synthesize name, price, category, itemid, hasImage;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString*) n price:(NSInteger) p category:(NSString*) c {
    if(self=[super init]){
        self.itemid = [SafeItem getNextId];
        self.name = [n copy];
        self.price = p; // this line throws error
        self.category = [c copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the default `assign` is what you want.

Frankly, this error doesn't make sense to me -- could there be something elsewhere in the code, such as an explicit implementation of `setPrice`? In the meantime, grasping at straws, try omitting the accesses via `self` in this initialiser.

(In all four of those assignments, actually. Your use of `copy` is consistent with direct access to the ivars. If you are using a `copy` setter, you don't need to `copy` the argument preemptively, and doing it as you do here -- with no corresponding `release` -- will give you leaks. Stick to one way or the other.)

Comment: Thanks.  I think there was something wrong in another part of the code (although there was definitely not an explicit implementation of any setters).  By the way, for future readers: don't *both* remove 'self' and 'copy' (e.g. "name = n"; do either "self.name = n" or "name = [n copy]", preferably the former).  I ended up removing both when trying various suggestions on this page and ended up with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to access the strings later.

Answer (score 1):

No, price should not be specified as `(copy)`. `copy` and `retain` are only used for objects, not primitive values like NSInteger.

By the way, you've specified `(copy)` as an attribute of the name and category properties, but you copy them again at assignment, which is redundant. Specifying `(copy)` for a property means that any time you set that property to a new value, `copy` is called automatically.

Comment: Not just redundant, also leaky!